# How many cube roots does 1 have modulo 162?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many cube roots does $1$ have modulo $162$

this is equivalent to saying how many solutions to $x^3 \equiv 1 $ mod$162$

all my attempts are leading a dead end any help appreciated

the fact that 162 is Non-Carmichael doesn't seem to be an use

also this is at elementary number theory level so no group theory please

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$162=3^4*2$

So you want

$x^3\equiv 1 \bmod 3^4$ and $x^3\equiv1 \bmod 2$, by the Chinese remainder theorem.

So $x^3\equiv1 \bmod 2.$

For the other part, $3^4$ has a cyclic multiplicative subgroup since $\lambda(3^4)=\varphi(3^4)$; by [Carmichael's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), we have $\varphi(3^4)=54$. Find a primitive root $p$ (we know one exists); your solutions will be $1,p^{18},p^{36}.$

$2$ is a primitive root: So we want $1,2^{18}$ and $2^{36}$. We can calculate both of these via exponentiation by squaring.

We get $2^{18}\equiv28$ and $2^{36}\equiv 55$.

So the solutions are $1,55$ and $109$.

Comment: 2 is a primitive root: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=order+of+2+mod+81

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what it means to be Charmicael then, the solution still works.

Answer (score 3):

You have $162 = 2 \times 3^4$, so

$$(\mathbb Z/162 \mathbb Z)^\times = (\mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z)^\times \times (\mathbb Z/3^4 \mathbb Z)^\times = (\mathbb Z/3^4 \mathbb Z)^\times.$$

Now, $(\mathbb Z/3^4 \mathbb Z)^\times = (\mathbb Z/3 \mathbb Z)^\times \times \mathbb Z/3^3 \mathbb Z$ is cyclic of order $\varphi(3^4)=54$, being a product of two cyclic groups of relatively prime orders $2$ and $3^3$. Since $3 \mid 54$, there are exactly $3$ elements in $(\mathbb Z/3^4 \mathbb Z)^\times$ of order $3$.

Comment: Nice, did you use charmicael's theorem to see it is cyclic?

Comment: Thanks @Jorge. Well, it is a product of two cyclic groups of relatively prime orders, hence it is itself cyclic.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to see $\mathbb Z/3^4\mathbb Z$ is cyclic.

Comment: @Jorge Are you sure that's what you mean?... It's a quotient of a cyclic group, so it's cyclic!

Comment: @BrunoJoyal Thanks for the answer but would have been great if you didn't use group theory

Comment: Nevermind, so how do we know the multiplicative group $mod 3^4$ is isomorphic to that direct product?

Comment: @Jorge Consider the reduction map $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\times \to (\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$. It is surjective with kernel the group $U$ of *princial units*, the units of the form $1+p\alpha$. Since the orders of $U$ and $\mathbb F_p^\times$ are relatively prime it follows that $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\times = \mathbb F_p^\times \times U$. So it's a matter of showing that $U$ is cyclic of order $p^{n-1}$. It clearly has $p^{n-1}$ elements, but to show that it is cyclic is a bit tricky.

Comment: Oh, I knew a proof that multiplicative groups $\bmod p^k$ with $p$ an odd prime are cyclic using lifting the exponent lemma.

Comment: @Jorge One way to prove that $U$ is cyclic is to pass to the $p$-adic numbers, and notice that the group of principal units of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p$, topologically generated by $1+p$. One way to do this is to use the $p$-adic log.

Answer (score 1):

As $162$ is of the form $2p^m$ where prime $p=3,m=4$

it has at least one primitive root $g$(say).

Applying [Discrete Logarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html) on $x^3\equiv1\pmod{162}\ \ \ \ (1)$,

$3$indx$_gx\equiv0\pmod{54}\ \ \ \ (2)$

as $\phi(162)=\phi(2)\phi(81)=1\cdot3^{4-1}(3-1)=54$

Now using  [Linear Congruence](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence) Theorem, as $(3,54)=3$ divides $0,$ equation$(2),$ has consequently $(1)$ will have exactly three solutions.

Comment: This approach is new to me but makes sense Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is equivalent to asking what $x$ satisfies $x^3 \equiv 1 \mod 162$

I wrote the simple script:

```
for x = 1 to 161
    if ((x*x*x) mod 162 == 1) print x
```

This gave me 1, 55, and 109.

Comment: appreciate i am looking for a question which could be answered in an exam

Comment: @MRK You needn't accept the answer but you should certainly upvote any answer that gives you a reasonable approach to think about the problem.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I needn't up vote either in my opinion because in my view strictly numerical answers or an algorithm are insufficient and wrong approach for a relatively simple problem. Would you tell someone to use wolfram alpha for every simple problem there would be no serious mathematicians. Just to let you know i rarely down vote answers and i didn't down vote  this answer.

Comment: @MRK I didn't say that you *need* to upvote, I said you *should* simply because the answerer did put some effort into answering *your* question. Now, I don't tell my students to run straight to the computer for "every simple problem" (any more than I tell them to come here for such a problem), but I *do* tell them that it is often valuable to think about a problem from multiple perspectives - including computational.